# What should I do when I see two duplicate user accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, duplicate-user

[jQuery, multiple tab groups on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465740/jquery-multiple-tab-groups-on-one-page)

`Carlos` posts, then `ClosDesign` says:

> @jyoseph, I originally posted this question. (Carlos). jyoseph is correct. That example in his answer is the correct one. I don't know how to close this question but that is it. Thank you very much. I can't vote. I need 15 reputation points, which I do not have yet or I would.

Sounds like a user who hasn't figured out the whole concept of SO. The accounts appear to have been created within 2 hours of each other, and they each only have one activity.

Pretty much just bringing this to attention, some of ya'll have better people skills than I do and some of you have tools to verify if these two are most likely the same user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In these cases, I find it more useful to flag one of the user's posts for moderator attention and provide the duplicate user id number.

Comment: Is it helpful that I linked to one of their posts instead since I didn't know what to do and that I provided both user names so that the mods wouldn't have to go digging? Additionally here there is room for discussion whereas if I had merely hit the "flag" button then there would be no meaningful discussion. I think you see what I mean

Comment: @drachenstern I am not sure any discussion is needed. I just think it would be more convenient for moderators to be notified directly rather than by following meta threads. SO policy is clear: You are not supposed to have more than one account which are used to vote for one's own activity. So, just give the mods a heads up and move on.